# Rails、deviseでブラウザを閉じたら、強制的にログアウトさせたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

timeoutableを使用すると、30分間アクティブではなかった場合、強制的にログアウトできますが、ブラウザを閉じて起動した際に、強制的にログアウトするにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？
session_storeはcookie_storeを使用しています。

Rails: 4.2.1
Devise: 3.4.1

Comment: 念のため確認しますが「タブを閉じたら」ではなく「ブラウザ（プロセス）を閉じたら」ということで間違いありませんか？

Comment: はい、タブではなく、ブラウザを閉じたら、です。もし、タブ閉じでもできるなら、ぜひ知りたいです！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

デフォルトでは `config/initializers/session_store.rb` でセッションに関する設定を行っています。これに、`expire_after: nil` を加えればブラウザ終了時にクッキーの情報を**ブラウザが**削除します。

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: 'xxxxxxxx', expire_after: nil
```

**注意**: 一般的なブラウザであればそのような動作が期待できるだけで、**全ての環境においてクライアントがクッキーを削除することは保証されていません**。

Comment: ありがとうございます！ブラウザ毎に挙動が違う可能性があるんですね・・`expire_after: nil`を設定して、Chromeで試したところ、ブラウザ終了してもログイン状態が保持されたままだったので、残念でした・・

Comment: @akm 私の方では解除されました。いくつか確認してください「1. session_store.rbのコメント通りrailsは再起動しましたか?」「2. セッションクッキー（一般的にブラウザ閉じる）と言われるのは、プロセス毎に管理されます。chromeを複数ウィンドウにして、該当ウィンドウだけ閉じたのではなく全部閉じましたか?」「3. 実際に発行されているcookieの有効期限は、どうなっていますか? (F12 > Resources > Cookies から一覧表が見えます)」

Comment: @NorikazIshii ありがとうございます。1. 再起動しました 2. Chrome自体閉じました（command + q） 3. クッキーありました。ただ、"Expires: When the browsing session ends"となってましたが、何度ブラウザを再起動してもログインしたままです・・

Comment: @akm 私の知っている事例では、そのパターンは、chromeの「設定＞起動時」が「前回開いていたページを開く」にセットされている場合です。 この場合chromeは(正直この動作は納得しがたいのですが)、ブラウザ終了時の状況を再現する（＝擬似的に開いたまま）と扱うためセッションクッキーが消えません。　こいつに対応するのは、しんどそうです。

Comment: @NorikazIshii 正にそれでした！`expire_after: nil`を設定してもしなくても、「前回開いていたページを開く」の設定をやめると、ログアウトされました。まさかその設定が関係しているとは思わなかったです・・すごい勉強になりました、ありがとうございますm(__)m